# Cómo cambiar texto html con javascript, seleccionado una clase y cambiando la etiqueta adentro

Tags: javascript

```
<li role="presentation" class="course-nav-tab-curriculum">
   <a href="#tab-curriculum" data-toggle="tab">
       <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
        <span>Plan estudios</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

Mi objetivo es cambiar el texto de "Plan estudio" por "Lecciones"
solo puedo utilizar javascript y hasta el momento llevo esto:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("fa-cube");

var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].innerHTML = "Lecciones";
}
```

mi problema es que estoy cambiando la etiqueta "i" pero no el "span" que esta adentro, agradezco la ayuda en este pequeño problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primer punto.

Tus etiquetas están mal acomodadas pues si deseas que se acceda al texto del `nav` por medio de la clase que tiene la etiqueta `i` entonces esta última debe envolver a la primera así:

```
<i class="fa fa-cube">
        <span>Plan estudios</span>
</i>
```

Siguiente una vez que ese cambio sea realizado, puedes recuperar ese valor con el método de JS `querySelector` al cual le podemos escribir la regla de esta forma:

```
.fa-cube > nav
```

Pues le indicamos que tome la etiqueta `nav` que es hija de la tag que tiene esa clase

Finalmente para modificar el texto por el deseado hacemos uso de `innerHTML` de esta forma

```
elementoModificado.innerHTML = "Lecciones"
```

**EJEMPLO**

```html
    <li role="presentation" class="course-nav-tab-curriculum">
       <a href="#tab-curriculum" data-toggle="tab">
           <i class="fa fa-cube">
            <span>Plan estudios</span>
           </i>
       </a>
    </li>
    <script>
        let elementoModificado = document.querySelector(".fa-cube > span")
        elementoModificado.innerHTML = "Lecciones"
        
    </script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ayudo a resolver mi problema